# while loop with different parameter in query

Tags: xslt

I am able to do a while loop in my xsl using this code:

```
<!-- recursive named template -->
<template name="while">
    <variable name="VALUE">
        <!-- your evaluation -->
    </variable>
    <!-- evaluate and recurse -->
    <if test="$VALUE=0">
        <call-template name="while"/>
    </if>
</template>
```

Now I want that the parameter of my query changed whenever I call the "while" template.

The first time I call `//dbquery[@id='pers']/rows/row` I have a parameter pOrg='HR'. In the result I get some data. I want to use that data when I recall the template, but then with the parameter pOrg equal to the data I got in the previous query.

Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dbqueries>
  <dbquery id="pers">
    <descriptor>
      <database>xxx</database>
      <originalquery>SELECT distinct ORG_NUM,POST_NUM FROM tablename where org_num='pOrg'</originalquery>
      <parameters>
        <param name="pOrg" value="HR" />
      </parameters>
      <querystring>SELECT distinct ORG_NUM,POST_NUM FROM tablename where org_num='HR';</querystring>
    </descriptor>
    <columns>
      <column name="ORG_NUM" type="VARCHAR" />
      <column name="POST_NUM" type="VARCHAR" />
    </columns>
    <rows>
      <row ORG_NUM="HR" POST_NUM="MR" />
    </rows>
  </dbquery>
</dbqueries>
```

In this example I want that the `pOrg` parameter equal to '`MR`' the second time I call the while template.

Comment: Well, I'm confused. I've read this three times and I have no idea what your question is.

Comment: For each <row> in my XML I want to redo my sql with the value in post_num

Comment: in other words how can I call //dbquery[@id='pers']/rows/row with the parameter pOrg is equal to a specific value that I choose.

Comment: For each row, I can understand. A specific value that you choose? Choose how? Where? -- If you want to iterate over your rows, I suggest you edit your example to include at least two rows, and add the expected output of the transformation. Removing anything that's not necessary to demonstrate the problem would also help.

Comment: I want to reuse my query `SELECT distinct ORG_NUM,POST_NUM FROM tablename where org_num='pOrg'`. in a while loop but with a different parameter `pOrg`. for example when I first do my select my parameter pOrg='HR' and I get org_num = HR and post_num = MR. Then I want to redo that select statement but with the parameter pOrg equal to the previous post_num, here MR. I now get for example org_num=MR and post_num= BF. My query has to be now execute with the parameter pOrg = BF. And so on, till I get null in the post_num.

Answer (score 0):

Though not sure about the wanted output, just an example as suggestion in case I understand the requirement right:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="dbqueries">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//row" mode="while">
      <xsl:with-param name="rowParam" select="'HR'"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="row" mode="while">
    <xsl:param name="rowParam"/>
    <xsl:param name="post_num" select="false()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="VALUE">0</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="param" select="$rowParam"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:if test="$VALUE = 0 and not($post_num)">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="while">
        <xsl:with-param name="rowParam" select="@POST_NUM"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="post_num" select="true()"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<row param="HR">HRMR</row>
<row param="MR">HRMR</row>
```

The first time templates are applied to `row` the parameter `HR` is used, which I guess you already retrieve in your current XSLT so I've just used it as static parameter in the example. The template matching `row` has two parameters: `rowParam` and `post_num`. `post_num` is `false()` the first time the template is called and is set to `true()` when the template is called for the second time with the value of `POST_NUM` of the current row.